# product through orders logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app where a user can both create products and purchase products through orders.

There is a field called usermode in my usertable that sets the user to either a store_owner or customer.

- IF usermode = 'Store_Owner'

  - I want my products index to show the products that are created by the current_user if

OR

- IF usermode = 'Customer'

  - I want my products index to show the products purchased by a user through orders>line items>products

I am new to rails and not sure whether I need to put this logic in the model, create separate controllers, or do some kind of if statement inside my existing product controller index. I think it should go in the controller index.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do something like this in my product controller:

```
if current_user.usermode =="Store_Owner" then
  @dashboards = current_user.dashboards.active.order(:title)
elsif current_user.usermode =="Customer" then
  @dashboards = Dashboard.joins(line_items: :order).where('orders.user_id' => current_user.id).all.uniq

end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion,

I would put the same logic in same controller. In both case (**Store_Owner** or **Customer**) you are showing **the same datatype (Products)**. The only change b/w these two case is that your **data is different**. ROR is about DRY. So I think there is no need to create new view template for this. However some believe that each action in controller must represent single functionality (to reduce the clutter in controller). That means less conditional statements in  controller. So you have this two choices:

I think the first one is better approach

1. Create single view file. write a method in model like following

   ```
   def self.product_data_of(user) # The self indicate class methods
       # check with if else that user is Store_Owner or Customer
       # return appropriate data
   end
   ```

   Call this method from controller like this(I have assumed the class name is Product)

   ```
   @products = Product.product_data_of(current_user)
   ```

   And you can use this @products variable in view file.
2. Create single view file write two different methods in controller but render the same view file. In this case no need to create new method in model. But still I would prefer the previous approach.

**Edit**

The general way is

1) **View**: The logic related to `how we will show` will be here

2) **Model**: The logic related to `What data` or `changes on data` will be here.

3) **controller**: The logic related to the flow like `fetch data from model` and `decide which page to render/redirect`

Comment: This is just general opinion there are some cases where other approaches are better then this. But in most cases you find this one better.

Comment: def self.product_data_of(user) goes inside the product.rb?

Comment: and also what sort of logic goes inside it?